# GWTTestCase - No Tests Found

Tags: java, gwt, junit

I'm running in eclipse juno with get 1.7.5 trying to set up junit testing. I added the junit jar from the juno plugin folder. I've set the option for junit 4.

I created a new get project 'MyJunitProject' and with one class under client 'MyFirstGWTTestCase.' Here is the code.

```
package com.client;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase;

 public class MyFirstGWTTestCase extends GWTTestCase {

@Override
public String getModuleName() {
    return "com.MyJunitProject";
}

@Test
public void myFirstTest() {
    assertTrue(true);
}

}
```

I get the following error:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in com.client.MyFirstGWTTestCase
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
at junit.framework.TestSuite$1.runTest(TestSuite.java:97)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunatly, GWT test cases are all running using the JUnit 3 model, not JUnit 4. This means that the `@Test` annotation doesn't mean anything, and that your methods must start with the word test. So instead of

```
//wrong! at least as of GWT 2.5 in a GWTTestCase
@Test
public void myFirstTest() {
    assertTrue(true);
}
```

you should write

```
public void testMyFirstTestCase() {
    assertTrue(true);
}
```

It doesn't matter what the rest of the method name is, as long as it begins with 'test'.

Comment: I had tried Junit 3 and got an error with org.mortbay.thread.Timeout exception. I found this article http://blog.elitecoderz.net/org-mortbay-thread-timeout-exception-on-new-gwt-webapplication-with-instantiations-gwt-designer-or-windowbuilder-pro/2010/05/ and when I moved the GWT library above the appengine the problem went away. Now I'm in business. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of GWTTestCase.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gwt/gwt_junit_integration.htm

Follow the steps given in above link.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using log4j / slf4j, check whether you have log4j properties in test/resources folder